# What causes python socket timeout

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, urllib

I have a simple Python code running on Linux (Raspbian) and connecting to a server using `urlopen`(basically this is using Python `socket`) :

```
 req = urllib.request.Request('myServer', data = params, headers = head)
 try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout = 20)
 except:
```

From [socket timeout doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts)

- `timeout=None` will act in `blocking` mode this is not what I want as It will hang forever if I have not internet connection
- `timeout=0` will act in `non-blocking` mode, but using it then I get error 115 (Operation now in progress)
- `timeout=20` will act in `timeout` mode, blocking for 20s and escaping if not able to create the connection

My questions:

1. Why is the `non-blocking` mode **always** failing ? (It may be a misconception but I thought it should work sometimes and not fail always)
2. What sometimes causes the 20s timeout to occur ? (80% of the case the `urlopen` will execute in 1-2s, 20% timeout)

Comment: non-blocking to contact a distant site? I would say that's bound to always fail. You said yourself that the site sometimes takes more that 20 seconds to reply.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't know if the website is the cause of the delay . How can I confirm this hypothesis ?

Comment: I would say that non-blocking on a connection open is not realistic. non-blocking works if for instance you're reading a message queue that has already a message posted in it. But if it's empty it exits immediately.

Comment: I understand your position but : Why would the website not accept the connection immediately ? Why does it take 20s sometimes ? is this normal/realistic ?

Comment: No strictly related to question, but you really shouldn't use `try / bare except`, especially when debugging (but really in any production code). By using bare except you threw away all information provided by interpreter which may be helpful for debugging...

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thank you for the hint. The original code is not from me and I was already modifying the bare except to remove them.